# MP3 Trimming On Windows Phone 8.1

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1

I'm looking for a way to split an mp3 file on windows phone 8.1, I've searched and search but there is barely any libs for windows phone, of which most are obsolete.
If someone could please point me in the right direction.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Since you are in Windows Phone 8.1 you can split the file using a method in Code Behind or ViewModel. You can use [NAudio](http://naudio.codeplex.com/) library for that.

The following code uses NAudio functions to split a mp3 file.

```
string nMP3Folder = "FOLDER PATH";
string nMP3SourceFilename = "SOURCE MP3 FILENAME";
string nMP3OutputFilename = "YOUR OUTPUT MP3 FILENAME";

using (Mp3FileReader rdr = new Mp3FileReader(nMP3Folder + nMP3SourceFilename))
{
    int count = 1;
    Mp3Frame objmp3Frame = reader.ReadNextFrame();
    System.IO.FileStream _fs = new System.IO.FileStream(nMP3Folder + nMP3OutputFilename, System.IO.FileMode.Create, System.IO.FileAccess.Write);

while (objmp3Frame != null)
{
    if (count > 500) //retrieve a sample of 500 frames
        return;

    _fs.Write(objmp3Frame.RawData, 0, objmp3Frame.RawData.Length);
    count = count + 1;
    objmp3Frame = rdr.ReadNextFrame();
 }

 _fs.Close();
}
```

Comment: I Cannot Add Naudio to a windows phone app it wont do it through nuget and if i do it manually when i try to build i get the errors Cannot resolve Assembly or Windows Metadata file 'System.Windows.Forms.dll' 
Type universe cannot resolve assembly: System.Windows.Forms, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c*****e089.

Comment: Try to install NAudio through package manager console. Type the following in package manager console: PM> Install-Package NAudio

Comment: i just get this error Successfully uninstalled 'NAudio 1.7.2'.
Install failed. Rolling back...
Install-Package : Could not install package 'NAudio 1.7.2'. You are trying to install this package into a project that targets 'WindowsPhoneApp,Version=v8.1', but the package does 
not contain any assembly references or content files that are compatible with that framework. For more information, contact the package author.
At line:1 char:1
+ Install-Package NAudio

Comment: Then it seems NAudio is not compatible with WinRT. See this link: http://naudio.codeplex.com/discussions/561074

Comment: Any Other Ideas On How To Split An MP3 ?

Comment: You can go through the NAudio code from GitHub and copy the functions that you need into your own class. This may work.